# Не удаётся выполнить миграцию и обновление базы данных SqlServer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef

Используется база данных SqlServer. EntityFramework 7.0.5

Entity

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
}
```

TokenEntity

```
public class TokenEntity : Entity
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Token { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LexiconEntity> Lexicon { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LexiconEntity> Lexicon2 { get; set; }
}
```

LexiconEntity

```
public class LexiconEntity : Entity
{
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public double? Weight { get; set; }

    public Guid TokenId { get; set; }
    public TokenEntity Token { get; set; }

    public Guid Token2Id { get; set; }
    public TokenEntity Token2 { get; set; }
}
```

Хочу создать таблицу, которая будет хранить в себе векторы, но после вызова add-migration init вылезает ошибка Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'LexiconEntity.Token' of type 'TokenEntity'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

UPD:

После того, как изменил TokenEntity на:

```
public class TokenEntity : Entity
{
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Token { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(LexiconEntity.Token))]
    public virtual ICollection<LexiconEntity> Lexicon { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(LexiconEntity.Token2))]
    public virtual ICollection<LexiconEntity> Lexicon2 { get; set; }
}
```

add-migration init сработал, но на update-database выпала ошибка `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Lexicon_Tokens_TokenId' on table 'Lexicon' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.`

UPD 2:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TokenEntity>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Lexicon)
                .WithOne(x => x.Token)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.TokenId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    modelBuilder.Entity<TokenEntity>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Lexicon2)
                .WithOne(x => x.Token2)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.Token2Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Миграция и обновление работает, но добавление записей не срабатывает и выбрасывается исключение при попытке сохранить добавленную запись Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Tokens'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Tokens'. The duplicate key value is (1c7e2668-628d-43a4-9748-362551a96eae).

Если же меняю DeleteBehavior.Restrict на Cascade, то при попытке обновить базу данных появляется ошибка: `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Lexicon_Tokens_TokenId' on table 'Lexicon' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.`

Comment: Вы пытаетесь модель языка программирования напрямую перенести в модель базы данных. А это очень сложно или вообще невозможно. Этому даже есть специальное название: [Object–relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_impedance_mismatch)

Comment: @aepot Да, прошу прощение, уже исправил вопрос и его заголовок

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вы имеете ввиду, что такую архитектуру в SqlServer нельзя сделать? (по крайней мере, в статье написано об этом) Можете подсказать, как тогда повторить структуру: [слово-слово-вектор], но изменить архитектуру так, чтобы всё работало?

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

Entity:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Lexicon:

```
public class LexiconEntity : Entity
{
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public double? Weight { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid TokenId { get; set; }
    public TokenEntity Token { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid Token2Id { get; set; }
    public TokenEntity Token2 { get; set; }
}
```

Token:

```
public class TokenEntity : Entity
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Token { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LexiconEntity> Lexicon { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LexiconEntity> Lexicon2 { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public DbSet<LexiconEntity> Lexicon { get; set; }

public DbSet<TokenEntity> Tokens { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TokenEntity>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Lexicon)
                .WithOne(x => x.Token)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.TokenId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    modelBuilder.Entity<TokenEntity>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Lexicon2)
                .WithOne(x => x.Token2)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.Token2Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Всё работает, но есть проблема: когда пытаемся добавить уже существующее слово (из таблицы Token) в таблицу Lexicon, появляется ошибка о том, что ключ является дубликатом. В противном случае, если слова нет и оно является новым, то оно добавляется в Token и запись в Lexicon успешно создаётся. Следовательно, связь, которая образовывается - один к одному, а это не является совсем правильным результатом

UPD. Решение описанной выше проблемы:

Добавление данных происходило в следующем порядке: Controller -> Service -> Repository -> DbContext. Controller отдавал в Service Dto класс, Service маппил в Entity, Repository вставлял в таблицу через Context. Код:

Controller:

```
var model = new LexiconDto()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Token = entities.First(),
    Token2 = entities2.First(),
    Weight = lexicon.Weight,
    LTH = lexicon.LTH
};

var entityId = await _lexiconService.Create(model);
```

Service:

```
public virtual async Task<Guid> Create(TDto model)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<TDto, TEntity>(model);
    entity.CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;
    entity.Revision = 1;
    entity.IsDeleted = false;

    var result = await Repository.Add(entity);

    Logging(OperationType.Added, result).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result;
}
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<Guid> Add<T>(T newEntity) where T : Entity
{
    var entity = await Context.Set<T>().AddAsync(newEntity);
    await SaveChangesAsync();
    return entity.Entity.Id;
}
```

Проблема заключалась в том, что в LexiconEntity существовал класс Token, который у меня был не null и поэтому при вызове `SaveChangesAsync` добавлял не только в таблицу Lexicon, но и в таблицу Token. Решение оказалось довольно-таки простым. Указывает в LexiconEntity для свойств, содержащих Token, модификатор virtual:

```
public class LexiconEntity : Entity
{
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public double? Weight { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid TokenId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid Token2Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TokenId))]
    public virtual TokenEntity Token { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Token2Id))]
    public virtual TokenEntity Token2 { get; set; }
}
```

А в Service делаем следующее:

```
public virtual async Task<Guid> Create(TDto model)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<TDto, TEntity>(model);
    entity.CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;
    entity.Revision = 1;
    entity.IsDeleted = false;

    //решение
    foreach (var virtualProp in entity.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual))
        virtualProp.SetValue(entity, null);
    //

    var result = await Repository.Add(entity);

    Logging(OperationType.Added, result).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result;
}
```

Таким образом, с помощью рефлексии находим виртуальные свойства и "обнуляем" их